# "Pancake glutton" exercise; what to do if user inputs two or more equal values

Tags: c++

Okay so there's been a couple similar questions like mine on this site but since no one has the same code as me my question didn't get answered. 
I'm trying to teach myself programming and I'm working on this exercise I found online called "Pancake glutton".

So here's my question: With my code both parts of the task can be done, but only as long as the user doesn't input that two or more people ate the same amount of pancakes because then the program outputs that multiple people ate the most/least amount of pancakes which isn't as clean as I'd like it to be. How can I solve this and get my program to have an extra option for multiple people eating the same amount of pancakes? Even just a tiny change so that it says "Person x ate the most, person y ate the least, and person z also ate the least" would be good enough for me..

Here's the "Pancake glutton" exercise:
"Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10)
Once the data has been entered the program must analyze the data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast.

★ Modify the program so that it also outputs which person ate the least number of pancakes for breakfast."

```
int main(){

    cout << "Enter the number of pancakes eaten by every person." << endl;
    int personNum[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int i = 0;
    int pN1, pN2, pN3, pN4, pN5, pN6, pN7, pN8, pN9, pN10; 
    int pancakeNum[]{pN1, pN2, pN3, pN4, pN5, pN6, pN7, pN8, pN9, pN10};

    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        cout << "Person " << personNum[i] << ": ";
        cin >> pancakeNum[i];
    }

    int pancakeMax = *max_element(pancakeNum, pancakeNum+10);

    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        if(pancakeMax == pancakeNum[i]){
            cout << "Person " << personNum[i] << " ate the most 
                             pancakes (" << pancakeMax << ")." << endl;
        } 
    }

    int pancakeMin = *min_element(pancakeNum, pancakeNum+10);

    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        if(pancakeMin == pancakeNum[i]){
            cout << "Person " << personNum[i] << " ate the least 
                             pancakes (" << pancakeMin << ")." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end its not coming down to a difficult algorithm or programming problem, but instead to how complex you want your output to appear (which is done with an appropriate level of `if-else` functions). E.g. below I showed a relatively simple enumeration solution to your problem - if however you want to have the grammatically complex output you provided you need to check with `if-else` when there is the case of more than one person having eaten the most/least amount.

A sample solution on how you could modify your code would be (keeping as much of your code as possible):

```
int main(){

    cout << "Enter the number of pancakes eaten by every person." << endl;
    int personNum[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int i = 0;
    int pN1, pN2, pN3, pN4, pN5, pN6, pN7, pN8, pN9, pN10; 
    int pancakeNum[]{pN1, pN2, pN3, pN4, pN5, pN6, pN7, pN8, pN9, pN10};

    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        cout << "Person " << personNum[i] << ": ";
        cin >> pancakeNum[i];
    }

    int pancakeMax = *max_element(pancakeNum, pancakeNum+10);

    cout << "The following persons ate the most amount of pancakes (" << pancakeMax << "):" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        if(pancakeMax == pancakeNum[i]){
            cout << personNum[i] << endl;
        } 
    }

    int pancakeMin = *min_element(pancakeNum, pancakeNum+10);

    cout << "The following persons ate the least amount of pancakes (" << pancakeMin << "):" << endl;
    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        if(pancakeMin == pancakeNum[i]){
            cout << personNum[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```